# Can I add separators in the Mac OS X Dock?

Tags: macos, dock

I have placed too many icons in my dock. There is a separator in the Dock between Applications and the Trash.

I want to add more separators in my dock for grouping, to identify groups of icons quickly.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Real separators for the Mac OS X Leopard dock](http://zzamboni.org/brt/2007/11/21/real-separators-for-the-leopard-dock/):

> Run the following commands from the Terminal:
>
> ```
> defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{ "tile-type" = "spacer-tile"; }'
> killall Dock
> ```
>
> Once the dock restarts, you should see a blank space after the last
>   application that is permanently in the Dock (before the icons for
>   applications that are currently running but not always in the Dock).
>
> You can now drag the empty spaces to where you want them, or
>   right-click on them and select "Remove from Dock" if you no longer
>   need them.